# When I switch between the Fragments ScrollView is not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I choose to work with the bottom navigation bar and started with some of the designing parts of the app, and for switching between the fragments done some back-end programming.
Everything is working fine except when I run the app for the first time, the scroll view page of the home fragment is working properly but when I switch to different fragment and come back to home fragment the scroll view is not working properly, it is showing like two scroll view one is static and another is scrolling.
Don't know what could be the problem, I am sharing the MainActivity.java and some snapshot of the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    private SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    private CartFragment cartFragment = new CartFragment();
    private AccountFragment accountFragment = new AccountFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        setFragment(homeFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_search:
                        setFragment(searchFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_cart:
                        setFragment(cartFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_account:
                        setFragment(accountFragment);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

image - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBUkTgzHwCFoQjP1gKs5Y6Z01xor1vbz/view?usp=sharing
image2  - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LJnLgJMck-zzGmgK5kgFDjFJNS_gJuao/view?usp=sharing
image3 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LB6nFJMuaxQUuc4oVctk1RjPx_-AGIXq/view?usp=sharing